# Merge [vb.net-2010] and [vb.net-2013] tags into [vb.net]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

There appears to be no value to having separate [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), [vb.net-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2010), and [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013) tags.

The various [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5), [.net-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) and other tags would be better used where there is a need to distinguish between the different features supported by different versions of the language.

The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag which is the nearest parallel does not have different versions by year.

In addition there is [no language difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#2013_.28VB_12.0.29) between VB version 11 (2012) and version 12 (2013) but there is no vb.net-2012 tag.

Should we replace any existing [vb.net-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2010) or [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013) tags with [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) or something better?

Comment: Should I revise this post to make it a different suggestion or create a new one?

Comment: Please, don't do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5915864) when on Meta, nothing as been decided on what to do with the tags.

Comment: I'll also add that the change hasn't been well received seeing the current score of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Stijn that there is only a weak link between the version of the .NET framework and the features supported by a language. (Though for LINQ and Async, there is an important amount of that feature that is part of the standard library shipped at that time.)

However, when one looks at the actual usage of the [vb.net-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2010) and [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013), the tag is never there to denote a question about a specific version of the language, but sometimes as a statement of "That is the IDE I use", and sometimes as "I will tag it with every related tag I find" even though that is not useful.

One could note that the situation is not much better for the C# language tags, as only part of the questions tagged with them are about the specific language version.

I would be in favor of removing [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013) and replacing its use by [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) + [visual-studio-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013), as I think that that is precisely what that tag means, and it is not too late to do that because that tag was created 1 month ago, and is found in only 10 questions (that I could see).

However, I would write off cleaning up [vb.net-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2010) as a lost cause, the way that [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) also is.

Comment: It seems like as soon as one person adds a tag others start using it without anyone thinking it through

Comment: Having vb.net + visual-studio-nnnn would be much better than having vb.net-nnnn

Answer (score 3):

Why are you changing the tags even if people here disagree with the change? You've made a lot of edits, some rejected and some not, to change the tags. It seems it wasn't a change that needed to be done. I could be wrong but doing it on your own with what seems to be more people not approving the change isn't good.

Can you stop editing and actually go with a burninate process and see if it gets meta people approval before making the change by yourself?

I'm answering to bring this question back on active view, so people will debate on the change again.

Answer (score 2):

The version of the .NET framework has nothing to do with the features supported by a language.

For C# we do have version tags, but that language follows a simple numbering scheme instead of using the year: [c#-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-1.2) [c#-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0) [c#-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0) [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) [c#-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0)

What we could do is make [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013) a synonym of [vb.net-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2012), and explain that there are no differences between those versions. There doesn't seem to be any question tagged with [vb.net-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2012) right now though.

A useful link on .NET, C#,and VS versioning (courtesy of [ProgramFOX](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18148935#18148935)): [C# in Depth: Untangling the Versions](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/versions.aspx)

Comment: Having year tags is misleading, dong things the C# way would be much better

Comment: @ClaraOnager you'll have to convince Microsoft of that. They seem to use years in official documents when referring to the versions for VB.NET

Comment: Can you link that because it seems to me that MS usually show a Visual Studio year, not a VB.NET year. e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/k6a6etxs(v=vs.120) SO is the only place I've ever seen VB referred to by year as in the tags mentioned.

Comment: @ClaraOnager [What's new in Visual Basic 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee336123.aspx), [Microsoft Press books on Visual Basic 20..](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/search/index.aspx?query=visual+basic), [Visual Basic 2010 Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4). I've seen MS refer to the non-year version number on a few occasions, but the majority seems to use the year version number.

Comment: Seems like MS are just as inconsistent as SO users. I still think that the SO tags are somewhat misleading though