# Tags change that didn't seem to be approved on Meta was partially made

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I happened to review edits made by the asker of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267987/773623) that removed the tags as per the linked question despite the negative score of the question.

I wanted to bring that question back to the attention of the community by answering it but it doesn't show in the active tab. I'm guessing this is due to its negative score.

Do we want the tags change to be made or not? Some of the edits have been approved, other haven't so at the moment we have a mixed state for those tags.

Now I have to bring the attention that question needs by asking this question.

Shouldn't, at least on meta, questions be brought into the active view despite their negative score? This might be a rare case.